# Checking in views whether the object passed in context exists or not

Tags: python, django

I am working on a basic django website . I am having a cart view as following:

```
def cart(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    context={
        'items':items,
        'order':order,
        'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request,"cart.html",context)
```

The items is the products that the customer has in his cart. I want to perform a check whether if the cart is empty(that is there are no items) then I can show a message that cart is empty and then can redirect to a certain page . I am trying to find a way to perform this check and show a message that cart is empty.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [**`exists()`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

```
context={
        'is_empty':order.orderitem_set.exists(),
        'items':items,
        'order':order,
        'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    }
```

Comment: I cant understand it? What will it do and how can I show the message using this whether the cart is empty or not

Comment: `is_empty` will be a boolean, which can be used in your template.

Comment: Like `{% if is_empty %} perform empty cart function {% else %} perform function when cart is not empty{% endif %}`